# Present alert from AppDelegate when app is ready for presenting an alert

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I'm using `Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)` and `Swift`.

I have this in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20.0, execute: {
    self.selectUser()
})
```

`selectUser()` will call a function that presents an alert to let user select his name.

When calling `selectUser()` without delay, the ViewController (I guess) isn't ready loaded and I'm getting a message like this:

> 2018-07-17 16:51:42.576783+0200 MyApp[2492:824301] Warning:
>   Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the
>   window hierarchy!

I think there is a better way to do this, something like: If the app is ready loaded to present an UIAlertController, call `selectUser()`.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `applicationDidBecomeActive` , but make sure it's called when you return from background also , so wrap code in once var if you don't like it to be called again

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to have a root viewController (storyboard or programmatic), the easiest way would be to present your alert inside the viewController because if `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is done, your "root"-viewController.view will be presented.